# ElasticSearch set parent for child object using ElasticSearch NEST .NET library

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, nest

Hi have a basic one to many structure ..

```
public class Person {
      public int PersonId { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Skill{
      public int PersonId { get; set; }
      public int SkillId { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Installed ElasticSearch NEST 5.x .. using .NET Framework 4.5 ..

Exploring the web from last 2 days but not able to find the way to set Person as a parent for Skill ..

I was assuming that NEST will automatically map the parent child relationship so I tried following

```
private ElasticLowLevelClient client = new ElasticLowLevelClient();    

public void CreatePerson(Person person)
        {
var parentResponse = client.Index(person, i => i.Index("myindex").Type("person").Id(person.PersonId));
    foreach (var skill in person.Skills)
    {
       var skillResponse = client.Index(skill, i => i.Index("myindex").Type("personskills").Parent(person.PersonId.ToString()).Id(skill.SkillId)); //here I am getting error
    }
}
```

Document for person creating without any issue but at the time of personskill doc I am getting this error:

*Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured*

While exploring I found may articles saying that I need to set the parent type to the child in mapping .. but how .. what is the procedure to custom map the index and how and where I should do that .. not getting any hint .. please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was unable to map the parent-child documents properly .. we can map them by creating index with predefined mapping or we can update the mapping

**Create Index**

```
private ElasticLowLevelClient client = new ElasticLowLevelClient();    
private CreateIndexDescriptor descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor("myindex")
              .Mappings(ms => ms
              .Map<Person>("person", m => m.AutoMap())
              .Map<Skill>("personskills", m => m.AutoMap().Parent("person"))
          );        

public void CreatePerson(Person person)
{
    client.CreateIndex(descriptor); //I am creating it here but one can create it in the class where we will create ElasticClient
    var parentResponse = client.Index(person, i => i.Index("myindex").Type("person").Id(person.PersonId));
    foreach (var skill in person.Skills)
    {
       var skillResponse = client.Index(skill, i => i.Index("myindex").Type("personskills").Parent(person.PersonId.ToString()).Id(skill.SkillId)); //here I am getting error
    }
}
```

**Update mapping**

```
public void CreatePerson(Person person)
        {
 client.Map<Skill>(m => m
                                 .Parent("person").Index("myindex")); //this will put the default mapping of default index
var parentResponse = client.Index(person, i => i.Index("myindex").Type("person").Id(person.PersonId));
    foreach (var skill in person.Skills)
    {
       var skillResponse = client.Index(skill, i => i.Index("myindex").Type("skill").Parent(person.PersonId.ToString()).Id(skill.SkillId)); //here I am getting error
    }
}
```

Here I have changed child document type to default value .. but one can set it in mapping. Hope this can help others.